# how to set marginTop to the Label in iOS like android

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard, margin

In android we use margin top like this but in ios how to use marginTop in storyboard?? sorry i am new to ios

```
<View
android:layout_marginTop = "5dp"
</View>
```

Answer (score 1):

In iOS, we use autolayout constraints. You can assign those in Interface Builder or you can give it programmatically. As @J. Doe suggested, that is how you can assign it in Interface Builder. To assign it programmatically, you can use anchors for deployment target above iOS 10.0 like this:

```
let View = UIView()
View.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
anyViewYouWantToAddViewTo.addSubview(View)
View.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: anyViewYouWantToAddViewTo.topAnchor, constant: 15).isActive = true
View.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: anyViewYouWantToAddViewTo.bottomAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
View.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: anyViewYouWantToAddViewTo.leadingAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
View.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: anyViewYouWantToAddViewTo.trailingAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
```

Answer (score 0):

See the picture, it is pretty simple:

[image]

Comment: Using storyboards, the image you have is essentially the same as adding a margin to the outside... It's really more of a hard padding because margins can overlap whereas this setting does not overlap with the view above it's setting.

Comment: Look into stack views, once you get the hang of them you'll love them